# show ProgressDialog while loading next activity, spinner not showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show a `ProgressDialog` while jumping from my `LoginActivity` to my `HomeActivity`, basically while `HomeActivity` is loading.

I am using a separate thread to call the intent of the `HomeActivity` while I am showing the `ProgressDialog` from the main thread in `LoginActivity`.

Everything seems to be working fine, it is just that the `ProgressDialog` is displayed **but there is no animated spinner.**

I am wondering if i am doing this correctly.

Here the relevant code from `LoginActivity`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText userID, userPass;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtX_srcLogin_userID);
        userPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtX_srcLogin_userpass);
        final Button bt_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bT_scrLogin_submit);


        bt_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                parseUserCredentials(userID.getText().toString(), userID.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }

    private void parseUserCredentials(String userId, String userPassword) {
        if ( userId.equals("userid") && userPassword.equals("1234") ) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Checking credentials",
                    "Please wait...", true, false);
        newThreadLoadActivity();
        }else {

            userID.setText("");
            userPass.setText("");
            userID.requestFocus();
            dialog.cancel();

        }

    }

    private void newThreadLoadActivity(){
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));

            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        dialog.cancel();

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The main idea is to show the `ProgressDialog` while`HomeActivity` loads, and cancel the `ProgressDialog` when `HomeActivity` is ready to be displayed.

Comment: how you need to show a progress bar? Since you didn't do any Api calls or background process

Comment: it is just for testing, so no server calls at this stage, the only purpose of this is to show the dialog while the next activity loads...there is no API call or something like that at this point

Comment: You can call `startActivity()` from a background thread, as you are doing, but the internals of `startActivity` ensure it is run on the main UI thread. So you are not going to get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: ok that seems to be the key of the issue, any possible fix??

Comment: okay your code is correct.since your new to android try to use  post delay handler

Comment: @prasanthMurugan examples of code would be appreciated in an answer form rather than a comment telling `try to use post delay handler` but still thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: @codeKiller check the answer

Comment: @codeKiller First of all you dont have any heavy running tasks before moving to the HomeActivity, in which the loader may be necessary. The operation that you are doing currently may take just micro seconds. Due to which the progress is not showing. Probably to just see the loader use the suggestion by prasanthMurugan.

Comment: ok! got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.It will make the delay for 10sec while moving to the next activity so your progress bar make be visible.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
 dialog.cancel();
 startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
}
}, 10000);
```

Comment: well, this works indeed but is not getting the desired effect, this basically shows the `ProgressDialog` for 10 secs, and then, then the `Runnable` triggers, it is still slowing down/stopping the spinner while `HomeActivity` loads....

Comment: the main idea is to show the `ProgressDialog` while`HomeActivity` loads, and cancel the `ProgressDialog` when `HomeActivity` is ready to be displayed

Comment: use  dialog.cancel(); before startActivity